# What type of integrals are these?

Tags: electromagnetism, differential-geometry, maxwell-equations, integration, calculus

Gauss's law $\rightarrow$

$$\oint\vec E\cdot d\vec A=\frac {Q_{encl}}{\epsilon_0}$$

Gauss's law for magnetism$\rightarrow$

$$\oint\vec B\cdot d\vec A=0$$

Faraday's law$\rightarrow$

$$\oint\vec E\cdot d\vec l=-\frac {d\Phi_B}{dt}$$

Ampere's law$\rightarrow$

$$\oint\vec B\cdot d\vec l=\mu_0\ \left ( i_C+\epsilon_0 \frac {d\Phi_E}{dt}\right )_{encl}$$

The notation looks similar to line integrals of vector fields; http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/LineIntegralsVectorFields.aspx

Comment: Hi tail_recursion, and welcome to Physics Stack Exchange! We prefer that you don't post formulas as screenshots, but use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/143136) instead. Could you edit your post accordingly?

Answer (score 3):

The first two are [surface integrals of vector fields](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_integral#Surface_integrals_of_vector_fields) over a closed surface.

The last two are [line integrals of vector fields](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_integral#Line_integral_of_a_vector_field) over a closed curve.

Answer (score 1):

The first two are integrals over the entire closed surface, i.e., the dot product is calculated for each elemental area of the surface (such that the elemental areas together cover the entire surface) and the electric/magnetic field at that particular point. The last two are integrals over the entire closed path, i.e., the dot product is calculated for each elemental length (which together comprise the path) and the electric/magnetic field at that point. 
Does this answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

To add a little on G.Smith's answer sending you to WP articles, it should be stressed out that the source you are using for Maxwell's equations in integral form has a sloppy notation for the closed surface integrals which makes them indistinguishable from the line integrals along closed contours.

What you write as:

$$\oint\vec E\cdot d\vec A=\frac {Q_{encl}}{\epsilon_0}$$

should actually be written as:

$$ \iint\limits_{S}\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\subset\!\supset \vec E \cdot \ d \vec A = \frac{Q_{encl, S}}{\epsilon_0}$$

And the same for the magnetic field. More precisely, I have used the conventions here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%27s_equations#Integral_equations